# A-frame check variable with function and show different gltf depending on the value

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, aframe, webvr

I am wondering how I can create something like this using JavaScript and A-frame (https://aframe.io).

I would like to create an onload function called `load()` that will check the value of a variable x and if x is one, the `gltf` with the id of 1 will show and the gltf's with the id of 2 and 3 will not be visible. The same goes for gltf's 2 and 3. How can I acomplish this? My code:

```
<script>
var x = 1;

</script>    
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<body onload="load()">

  <a-gltf-model  id="1" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/2556b706-79db-4661-ab72-d86cfd5b5649%2Fscene.glb?v=1622850633562" position="-0 6 -1" scale="0.01 0.01 0.01"></a-gltf-model>

  <a-gltf-model  id="2" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/6632f840-a210-4bdc-a62f-bc38e65ae48a%2Fscene%20-%202021-06-12T230318.001.glb?v=1623564342354" position="-0 6 -1" scale="0.01 0.01 0.01"></a-gltf-model>
  <a-gltf-model  id="3"src="https://cdn.glitch.com/6632f840-a210-4bdc-a62f-bc38e65ae48a%2Fwinter.glb?v=1623564477495" position="-0 6 -1" scale="0.01 0.01 0.01"></a-gltf-model>

<a-scene>


</a-scene>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the valid `id`s in an array and loop through each one, then remove correspondingly.

```js
const ids = [1, 2, 3];

function load() {
  var x = 1;
  ids.forEach((e) => {
    if (e != x) {
      document.getElementById(e).remove();
    }
  })
}
```

```css
a-gltf-model {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>

<body onload="load()">

  <a-scene>

    <a-gltf-model id="1" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/2556b706-79db-4661-ab72-d86cfd5b5649%2Fscene.glb?v=1622850633562" position="-0 6 -1" scale="0.01 0.01 0.01"></a-gltf-model>

    <a-gltf-model id="2" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/6632f840-a210-4bdc-a62f-bc38e65ae48a%2Fscene%20-%202021-06-12T230318.001.glb?v=1623564342354" position="-0 6 -1" scale="0.01 0.01 0.01"></a-gltf-model>
    <a-gltf-model id="3" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/6632f840-a210-4bdc-a62f-bc38e65ae48a%2Fwinter.glb?v=1623564477495" position="-0 6 -1" scale="0.01 0.01 0.01"></a-gltf-model>
    <a-plane width="100" height="100" position=" 0.00 0.00 0.00" rotation="-90 0 0" color="royalblue"></a-plane>


  </a-scene>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the example on this blog may be helpful:
https://medium.com/swlh/build-your-location-based-augmented-reality-web-app-a841956eed2c

have a single `<a-entity></a-entity>` component.
use your `load()` to dynamically change the `gltf-model` and `position` attributes.

maybe store the info in an array of sort like in the linked example above?